# Google GData YouTube API, Search?

Tags: objective-c, ios, macos, gdata

I have been trawling through all I can to do with the Google GData YouTube API and it's doing nothing but hurting my brain, Google do not make it clear to learn and there seems to be little content online about it (Objective-C iOS, Mac).

I just want to achieve a simple task: search YouTube, getting thumbnails, descriptions, titles etc for the search results. I am unsure of where to start.

Are there some good resources for learning the API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [YouTubeSample app](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/source/browse/trunk/Examples/YouTubeSample/YouTubeSampleWindowController.m) would be the most straightforward example.  You would need to first read and understand the [API library documentation](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/wiki/GDataObjCIntroduction).